# PHP shell_exec in windows not writing to LPT1

Tags: php, windows, apache, permissions, shell-exec

I'm porting some little piece of code I wrote from linux to windows, I basically need to push ZPL code to a zebra printer connected via usb. No problems with shell_exec and lp in linux.

On windows, I mapped the usb printer to LPT1, and no problems here, and if I echo my code (or copy a file) to LPT1 (in cmd), everything works. Like:

```
copy C:\zplcode.txt LPT1 *or* echo "zplcode here" > LPT1
```

my stuff gets printed.

Now, like I said this works flawless in cmd, but if I shell_exec this, it doesn't work. I thought shell_exec did not work at all, but it does. In fact, `echo shell_exec('ver')`returns my windows version. And where    `copy C:\zplcode.txt LPT1` returns "1 file copied" in cmd, `echo shell_exec('copy c:\zplcode.txt LPT1')` returns "0 files copied". This also happens if I try copying any normal file or echoing to them.

It's like apache doesn't have write permissions or something, still it's not like on linux where it has its own user, it's a service running as system... can you help? Thanks

edit2: I solved my problem by disabling UAC and forcing apache service to run as administrator, then doing `shell_exec("echo zplcode here > ///localhost//printer")` where printer is the name I assigned to my printer when sharing it. I guess the problem still exists, since I couldn't push data to LPT1 if I needed to (unless sharing it and doing what I did here).

Comment: `system` is still technically an account in windows.

Comment: vague debugging test: `exec('echo %USERNAME%')` and `shell_exec('echo %USERNAME%')`, see if there are any differences between the two. Can't see how, but who knows... Windows can be weird sometimes.

Comment: strange... both return the computer name followed by $

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: *technically* it's a security primitive; it lacks some of the properties of an account (e.g., no password, no expiry date, no full name).  The distinction isn't particularly relevant in this case though. :-)

Comment: You say you "mapped the USB printer to LPT1" ; such mappings are local to the user's logon session, or perhaps to the Remote Desktop session, I'm not certain.  Either way the service won't see it, even if configured to run under the same user account.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Now it's all clear, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you "mapped the USB printer to LPT1" ; such mappings are local to the user's logon session (or perhaps to the Remote Desktop session, I'm not certain).

Either way the service won't see it, even if configured to run under the same user account.  Each service gets a separate logon session, and as of Windows Vista, [only services run in Remote Desktop session 0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb203962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).